# Add root element to XML in Java

Tags: java, xml

I hava an XML String that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>500404</id>
<parentid>0</parentid>
<version>1</version>
<nodes>
    <id>1015252</id>
    <category>NODE</category>
    <modified>false</modified>
    <X>80</X>
    <Y>30</Y>
</nodes>
```

I want to programatically modify it by adding a root node tag called "model" .
I tried to parse the string using DOM, read all child nodes and then to create a new xml doc of type `Document` with a root node called "model" which has as child nodes all the nodes of the XML String I allready have. 
But it is giving me the following exception :
**The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.**

My code so far is :

```
String xmlString = "XML GOES HERE"
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inputstream = new InputSource(new StringReader(
                xmlString));
        Document doc = builder.parse(inputstream);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getChildNodes();
                Document doc2 = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc2.createElement("model");
        doc2.appendChild(rootElement);
                for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++)
            {
                Node childn = nodes.item(k);
                rootElement.appendChild(childn);
                         }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: The original is not XML - as it has no root, so no XML Parser can read it- you will have to use plain text tools (My normal comment on this is to ask the sender of that file  to please send a valid XML file - it is their bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that your xml string is not well formed ([see Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling)). The root element has to be unique. You have 4 "root" elements: `id`, `parentid`, `version` and `nodes`.

Thererfore it cannot be parsed using a XML parser that expects well-formed input. I' m afraid you have to modify the string as text either programmatically or by hand. Insert a start tag after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and add the corresponding end tag at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<model>` string after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and `</model>` to the end of file.
I guess it's not necessary to parse the whole document to add root element.